# Annotation attribute must be a class literal? Why? Constants should be fine too

Tags: java, testng, jls

Can someone explain why String and Class annotation parameters are expected differently? Why does the compiler require literals for Classes, wherby accepting constants for Strings as well?

Working example with Spring's @RequestMapping:

```
public class MyController {
    public static final String REQUEST_MAPPING = "/index.html";
    @RequestMapping(MyController.REQUEST_MAPPING) // ALL OK!
    ...
}
```

WTF example with TestNG's @Test:

```
public class MyControllerTest {
    public static final Class TEST_EXCEPTION = RuntimeException.class;
    @Test(expectedExceptions = MyControllerTest.TEST_EXCEPTION) // compilation error, WTF:
    // The value for annotation attribute Test.expectedExceptions must be a class literal
    ...
}
```

What does work of course is @Test(expectedExceptions = RuntimeException.class). But why? The only difference in the annotation parameter I see is its type: String vs Class. Why on earth would the Java compiler accept String constant as well but accept only class literals?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Java Language Specification doesn't permit you to use compile-time constants with parameters of type `Class`.  You can only use class literals.

The [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.7) has the following to say about suitable parameter values for annotations:

> An element type *T* is commensurate with an element value *V* if and only if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - *T* is an array type *E[]* and either:
>
>   - *V* is an *ElementValueArrayInitializer* and each *ElementValueInitializer* (analogous to a variable initializer in an array initializer) in *V* is commensurate with *E*. Or
>   - *V* is an *ElementValue* that is commensurate with *T*.
> - The type of *V* is assignment compatible ([§5.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#184206)) with *T* and, furthermore:
>
>   - **If *T* is a primitive type or String, *V* is a constant expression [(§15.28)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#5313).**
>   - *V* is not null.
>   - **if *T* is Class, or an invocation of Class, and V is a class literal [(§15.8.2)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#251530)**.
>   - If *T* is an enum type, and *V* is an enum constant.
>
> It is a compile-time error if the element type is not commensurate with the *ElementValue*.

I can't say why this restriction is in the JLS, however.

Comment: Wow, I totally miss the point of this. Why this restriction on Class? Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

I got the "annotation value must be a class literal" on the following:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/story/notifications",
        encoders = (StickerEncoder.class),
        decoders = (StickerDecoder.class))
```

This happening whilst following one of Oracles tutorials on websockets.  Turns out the video is not the 720p quality and the fuzziness hides the braces which look like curly brackets.  So the error disappears upon changing brackets (parentheses) for braces.

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/story/notifications",
        encoders = {StickerEncoder.class},
        decoders = {StickerDecoder.class})
```

hth anyone who may trip over the same in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Look this:

```
public static final Class TEST_EXCEPTION = RuntimeException.class;
```

The class should be a Throwable that the compiler is able to check. So, try this:

```
public static final Class<? extends Throwable> TEST_EXCEPTION = RuntimeException.class;
```

Comment: I intentionally left out generics, it is independent of that.

Comment: Well, in this case, I don't know. Looks like that this is an accidental limitation of the language, but I am not sure. :(

Answer (score 0):

***Room doesn't have a native support for storing dates***, you need to convert it to LONG values while inserting and reading to and from the database. Hence we are responsible to instruct the Room database on how to convert the data.

For that, thanks to room architecture, we have **TypeConverter** class. Well, don't get carried away, there isn't a special class that you can just extend and get things done, but its something you have to write from scratch but it does use Annotations to make it work with Room.

For example, while dealing with Dates :

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.TypeConverter;
import java.util.Date;

//Type-Converter Class for Room
public class DateConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    // Long value to Date value
    public static Date toDate(Long timestamp) {
        return timestamp == null ? null : new Date(timestamp);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    // Date value to Long value
    public static Long toTimestamp(Date date) {
        return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
    }
}
```

Now, we have to tell our Database class to use this TypeConverter Class using **@TypeConverters** (make sure to use plural version).

```
@Database(entities = {Entity.class}, version = 1)
@TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {...}
```

You are ready to rock!

Answer (score 0):

```
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
```

You must paste this in your project build.gradle(Project: MyApplication(Project Name))

```
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
```

You must paste this in your project build.gradle(Module:app)

There might be a problem with dependency or just with their naming.

If you want a full code example go for the link:

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/android-architecture-components-room-persistence-library