# Java Annotation

Tags: java, annotations

what will be correct Java annotation values in place of following?

```
@interface Demo
{
    Class obj();
    String class_name();
}
...
...
@Demo(obj=Class.forName("Example"),class_name=obj.getName())
```

i'm getting error as "annotation value must be a class literal"

Comment: check this:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604316/annotation-attribute-must-be-a-class-literal-why-constants-should-be-fine-too

Answer (score 0):

Annotations must be constant at compile time. Therefore, methods are not allowed.

The above annotation can be done with this:

```
@Demo(obj=Example.class, class_name="Example")
```

Answer (score 0):

Values passed to annotations must be known in compile-time, so you cannot use calls like `Class.forName`. Instead, you could use the class directly:

```
@Demo(obj = Example.class, class_name="com.exmaple.Example")
```